# In JS, If two function are called by unload in what order are they processed by the browser

Tags: javascript, function, onload

I am trying to call `newsize(picture_src)` after the function `resizeimg()`.
It appears that the function `newsize(picture_src)` is always called first.

The function `resizeimg()` has to be called first because it sets the `sizepic()` function that `newsize(picture_src)` uses to change the image `src`.

Here's my html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>TP n°1 - Mise en place d'une grille responsive</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>

    <link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script>
            if(window.innerWidth>1200){
                var sizepic='1200';
            }
            else if(window.innerWidth<1200 && window.innerWidth>900){
                var sizepic='990';
            }
            else if(window.innerWidth<990 && window.innerWidth>768){
                var sizepic='768';
            }
            else if(window.innerWidth<768 && window.innerWidth>590){
                var sizepic='590';
            }
            else if(window.innerWidth<590){
                var sizepic='petit';
            }

    function newsize(picture_src, picture){
                picture_src.src=='img/'+sizepic+'/'+picture+sizepic+'.jpg';
                alert(picture_src.src);
    }
    </script>

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>



    <div class="wrapper">

        <!-- 1ère ligne -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col100">
                 <div class="row">
                    <div class="col60 cs100">
                        <div id='september'class="xs-contenu">
                            <h1>Experience the web</h1>
                            <p><strong>September 2013 Club Theme</strong></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col40 cs100">
                        <div class="xs-contenu">
                            <div id='dv-icon'>
                                <img src='img/1200/iconchat.jpg'>
                                <img src='img/1200/icontwitter.jpg'>
                                <img src='img/1200/iconbasket.jpg'>
                                <img src='img/1200/iconfacebook.jpg'>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- 2nde ligne -->



        <!-- 3ème ligne -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class='col20 cs50'>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col100">
                        <div class="contenu">
                            <p class='square'>Design and styled with Ulkit.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col100">
                        <div class="contenu">
                            <img onload='newsize(this, 'cube')'src=""/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: `sizepic` appears local to `resizeimg` ; `picture_src` does not set `src` of `img` element

Answer (score 0):

`sizepic` appears local to `resizeimg`; `picture_src` does not set `src` of `img` element.

Try this:

1. Define `sizepic` outside of and before calling `resizeimg()`.
2. Remove the `onload` event from `body` that calls `resizeimg()`.
3. Pass `this` to `newsize()` (setting `picture_src` to `this`). Make sure to set the `onload` event to `null` during the function to prevent recursive calls the `newsize` after setting `src` of `picture_src`.

```html
<body>
  <script>
    // declare variable `sizepic`
    var sizepic;

    function resizeimg() {
      if (window.innerWidth > 1200) {
        sizepic = '1200';
        alert(sizepic);
      } else if (window.innerWidth < 1200 && window.innerWidth > 900) {
        sizepic = '990';
      } else if (window.innerWidth < 990 && window.innerWidth > 768) {
        sizepic = '768';
      } else if (window.innerWidth < 768 && window.innerWidth > 590) {
        sizepic = '590';
      } else if (window.innerWidth < 590) {
        sizepic = 'petit';
      }
      console.log("resizeimg called")
    };
    // call `resizeimg` here
    resizeimg();

    function newsize(picture_src) {          
      picture_src.src ="http://lorempixel.com/" + sizepic + "/" + sizepic;
      console.log("newsize called", picture_src, event);
      // remove `onload` event from `picture_src`
      picture_src.onload = null;
      }
  </script>
  <img onload="newsize(this)" src="http://lorempixel.com/1/1/" />
</body>
```

Comment: I just changed my code. I removed the resizeimg function and added another argument inside the newsize function: picture. Each picture will be different and will make up the path to find different img. It is not working.

Comment: newsize function is not called when the scripted is loaded

Comment: @WillyMercier That is because the `src` at  of `img` element is an empty string at `html` of updated Question `<img onload='newsize(this, 'cube')'src=""/>`. Tried including a valid URL at `src` attribute of `img` element at `html` `<img onload='newsize(this, 'cube')'src="/path/to/img"/>`

Comment: Ok this works great. but what does 'picture_src.onload = null' do?

Comment: _"what does 'picture_src.onload = null' do?"_ Removes `onload` event from that element, so that event handler for that element is not called recursively. Try at jsfiddle without `picture_src.onload = null` to view results of recursive call to `newsize`